Properties of inscribed angles in a circle in hyperbolic geometry.
Suppose we have a line of constant geodesic curvature $\kappa$ in the standard hyperbolic plane (Gaussian curvature $-1$). This line belongs to one of four types of curves: a straight line ($\kappa=0$, I mean "straight" in the hyperbolic sense, the shortest path connecting any two points on it), a hypercircle ($0<|\kappa|<1$), a horocycle ($|\kappa|=1$) and a circle ($|\kappa|>1$). I am interested in the high geodesic curvature region of $\kappa$ ($|\kappa|>1$), when the line closed on itself and forms a closed loop (called a circle). Suppose we have an arc $AB$ of length $l$ of this circle and another point $C$ on this circle that is not on this arc. Suppose also that the center of arc $AB$ is $M$ and we know the arc length of the circle between $C$ and $M$, which we denote $s$.
My question is: what is the formula for the inscribed angle $\angle ACB$ in terms of the two arclengths $l,s$ and the geodesic curvature $\kappa$ of the circle?
Since for $|\kappa|>1$ we have a circle, which is the locus of all points with constant distance from a fixed point $O$ (the center), the central angle $\angle AOB$ is easy to calculate: it is $2\pi \frac{l}{p}$ where $p$ is the perimeter of the circle (there is a well-known formula for $p$ involving hyperbolic sine). But since I am dealing with inscribed angle the symmetry consideration does not help...
I tried to search for such a formula without success by Googling expressions like "inscribed angles in circles in the hyperbolic plane". A good reference that discusses this formula is enough for me, even if the answer will not prove it here.

this may help. http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf   although I wrote everything as intrinsic

@WillJagy - I am not sure I understand how your article helps here... your article deals with compass and straigtedge constructions in $\mathbb{H}^2$, how is it related to a general formula for inscribed angle?

Mostly, I couldn't make out what you intended as a diagram....

I don't have time to write up a derivation at the moment, but perhaps you could sanity-check this formula for the case of curvature $k>1$:
$$\tan\angle ACB = \frac{2kh \sin\angle MOA}{(k^2+h^2) \cos\angle MOA - \cos\angle MOC} = \frac{2kh \sin(\frac12h\ell)}{(k^2+h^2) \cos(\frac12h\ell) - \cos(hs)}$$
where $h := \sqrt{k^2-1}$. In angular form, we can at least see that for infinitesimal circles, $k\to\infty$, this reduces to $\tan\angle ACB=\tan\angle MOA$; hence, $\angle ACB=\angle MOA$, the Euclidean Inscribed Angle Theorem.

$\newcommand{\cis}{\operatorname{cis}}$
In the Poincaré (unit) Disk Model, consider an origin-centered circle of (Euclidean) radius $r_e$, and points $M$, $A$, $B$, $C$, as well as $C'$ (the inverse of $C$ in the boundary circle) with coordinates
$$M := r_e \cis0 \quad A := r_e \cis\theta \quad B := \cis(-\theta) \quad C := r_e \cis\phi \quad C' := \frac1{r_e}\cis\phi \tag1$$
where I'm abusing notation to define $\cis\theta := (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

It's straightforward to find the centers of Euclidean circles $\bigcirc ACC'$ and $\bigcirc BCC'$ that model hyperbolic lines $AC$ and $BC$, and then to use a vector dot product to find the cosine of the angle between the Euclidean tangents at $C$ (which models the hyperbolic $\angle ACB$). As it happens, the tangent of that angle has a nicer form:
$$\tan\angle ACB = \frac{(1 - r_e^4) \sin\theta}{(1 + r_e^4) \cos\theta - 2 r_e^2 \cos\phi} = \frac{\frac12\left(\frac1{r_e^2} - r_e^2\right) \sin\theta}{\frac12\left(\frac1{r_e^2} + r_e^2\right) \cos\theta - \cos\phi} \tag2$$
Note that for an "infinitesimal circle" ($r_e\to 0$), this reduces to $\tan\angle ACB=\tan\theta$. We may conclude $\angle ACB=\frac12\angle AOB$, which is the Euclidean Inscribed Angle Theorem.
To translate $(2)$ into hyperbolic elements, we observe that

The circle's hyperbolic radius, $r$, satisfies
$$r_e=\tanh\tfrac12r \tag3$$

The circle's geodesic curvature, $\kappa$, is given by $$\kappa = \coth r = \frac12\left(\frac1{r_e}+r_e\right)\tag4$$

OP's hyperbolic arc-lengths are given by
$$\ell:= \angle AOB\,\sinh r = 2\theta\,\sinh r \quad\text{and}\quad 
s:= \angle MOC\,\sinh r = \phi\,\sinh r \tag5$$


Defining $\lambda := \sqrt{\kappa^2-1} = \operatorname{csch} r = \frac12\left(\frac1{r_e}-r_e\right)$, we have
$$\theta = \tfrac12\ell\lambda \qquad \phi=s\lambda \qquad
\frac12\left(\frac1{r_e^2}-r_e^2\right)=2\kappa\lambda \qquad
\frac12\left(\frac1{r_e^2}+r_e^2\right)=\kappa^2+\lambda^2 \tag6$$
so that $(2)$ becomes
$$\tan\angle ACB = \frac{2\kappa\lambda \sin(\tfrac12\ell\lambda)}{(\kappa^2+\lambda^2) \cos(\tfrac12\ell\lambda) - \cos(s\lambda)} \tag{2'}$$

Note. One can calculate
$$\lim_{\kappa\to1}\;\tan\angle ACB = \frac{8\ell}{16 +\left(4s^2 - \ell^2\right)}= \frac{\frac12\left(s+ \frac12\ell\right)-\frac12\left(s- \frac12\ell\right)}{1 +\frac12\left(s+ \frac12\ell\right)\cdot\frac12\left(s-\frac12\ell\right)} \tag7$$
which is consistent with OP's own calculation for the angle inscribed in a horocycle (which has unit curvature).

Addendum. To complete the trifecta ...
For a hypercycle (aka, equidistant curve) with curvature $\kappa <1$ and radius $r$ (the distance from any of its points to its axis (the line sharing the curve's ideal points)), we have
$$\tan\angle ACB = \frac{2 \kappa \lambda \sinh(\frac12\ell\lambda )}{\cosh(s\lambda) - (\kappa^2 - \lambda^2) \cosh(\frac12\ell\lambda)} \tag{2''}$$
where $\lambda := \sqrt{1-\kappa^2}$.
This incorporates these relations:

Arc-lengths satisfy
$$\ell := |A'B'|\,\cosh r = 2|M'A'|\,\cosh r \quad\text{and}\quad s:=|M'C'|\,\cosh r$$ where $P'$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to the hypercycle's axis.

Curvature and radius satisfy $$\kappa = \tanh r \quad\text{and}\quad \lambda = \operatorname{sech} r$$ The only reference I've found for this is in a comment from @mr_e_man to this Math.SE question. It's also consistent with the notion that expressions $\cosh(|M'A'|)$ and $\cosh(|M'C'|)$ in the curvature-less version of the formula "should" have the form $\cosh(\frac12\ell\lambda)$ and $\cosh(s\lambda)$ by analogy with $(2')$.



I think I've got the idea how to calculate the incsribed angle, but meanwhile only for the case of horocycle (geodesic curvature $\kappa = 1$). I think It is easiest to look at the problem by the Poincare's upper half plane model. In this model horocycles are represented by either circles that are tangent to the $x$ axis, or lines parallel to the $x$ axis.
For simplicity, let us assume the horocycle is a line parallel to $x$ axis, $y=h$. To calculate an inscribed angle, just pick up three points $C,A,B$ on this line, such that the distance between $A$ and $B$ along the horocyclic arc is $l$ according to the metric of the model ($ds=\frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{y}$), and the distance between $C$ and $A$ is $s-\frac{l}{2}$. Construct the lines passing between $C$ to $A$ and $B$; these lines are hemicircles orthogonal to $x$ axis that intersect $y = h$ at points $C,A$ and $C,B$. Since the upper half plane model is conformal, the required angle $\angle ACB$ is the angle between the circular arcs $CA,CB$ at point $C$.
Than a simple calculation of angles shows the answer is:
$$\angle ACB = \mathbb{arctan}(\frac{s+\frac{l}{2}}{2})-\mathbb{arctan}(\frac{s-\frac{l}{2}}{2})$$
Just for comparison, in euclidean geometry the inscribed angle depends only on the length of arc $AB$, and is equal to $\frac{l}{2r}$ ($r$ is the radius of circle).
Notice: the answer is independent of the choice of $h$; this is expected, since in the metric of this model the length element is inversely proprtional to $y$, so the representation of an horocyclic arc of length $l$ on the line $y = h$ is a segment of length $h\cdot l$ on this line, so when calculating the tangents of the required angles the arbitrary constant $h$ disappears.
I still don't know how to tackle the general case of circles (with geodesic curvature $|\kappa|>1$)...
